# fullText with multiple `or` throwing an error in parse server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Hi I am using `fullText` with multiple `or` statement but parse server throwing an error:
Here is my statement

```
var query1 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query1.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[0]);
var query2 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query2.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[1]);
var query3 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query3.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[2]);
var query4 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query4.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[3]);
var query5 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query5.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[4]);
var query6 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query6.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[5]);
var query7 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query7.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[6]);
var query8 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query8.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray[7]);
orQuery = Parse.Query.or(query1, query2, query3, query4, query5, query6, query7, query8);

return motherQuery.matchesQuery(pattern, orQuery);
  motherQuery.limit(1000);
  motherQuery.find({
      useMasterKey: true
  })
```

Parse server throwing below error:

```
[31merror[39m: Error generating response. ParseError {
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632775+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 1,
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632776+00:00 app[web.1]: message: MongoError: Too many text expressions
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632778+00:00 app[web.1]: at queryCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:247:25)
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632779+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:531:18
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632781+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632783+00:00 app[web.1]: name: 'MongoError',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632784+00:00 app[web.1]: message: 'Too many text expressions',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632785+00:00 app[web.1]: ok: 0,
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632787+00:00 app[web.1]: errmsg: 'Too many text expressions',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632788+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 2,
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632789+00:00 app[web.1]: codeName: 'BadValue',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632791+00:00 app[web.1]: operationTime: Timestamp { bsontype: 'Timestamp', low: 6, high_: 1574671603 },
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632792+00:00 app[web.1]: '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] },
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632793+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632794+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

**Here is what I want:**
I have a string column(wishlistSearchString) in table. and a search string (offerSearchString).

each word in wishlistSearchString is checked separately with all words in offerSearchString (no "exact" search, but "contains")

only if ALL words in wishlistSearchString have been found (AND) we have a match

wishlistSearchString "Picass" and offerSearchString "Picasso" is a match

wishlistSearchString "Picassoo" and offerSearchString "Picasso" is NOT a match

wishlistSearchString "Picass, painting" and offerSearchString "Picasso, painting" is a match

wishlistSearchString "Picass, painting" and offerSearchString "Picasso, Pablo, painting" is a match

wishlistSearchString "Picass, painting" and offerSearchString "Picasso, photography" is NOT a match

**Based on the offer string I want to get records from table**

Comment: Unfortunately you can only add one full text search constraint per query.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thanks for the reply. What will be a solution in that case?

Comment: Do you want to return all objects that match at least one of the terms, right? Something like this should solve your problem: `query.fullText("searchString", searchTermArray.join(' '));` Take a look at this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I have updated question. Please check the `Here is what I want`   block

Comment: I am afraid you will not be able to do that with full text search. 1) it does not do partial matches (Picass vs Picasso) 2) it does not check if all words matches. You will probably need to transform `wishlistSearchString` into an array of strings and use `includeAll` constraint (it will not do the partial match as well). Or you can try to write a RegExp or even combine queries with aggregate to achieve what you need (it will probably turned out being an expensive query for your db).